# how to check single file for doxygen complience

Tags: doxygen

I created a `Doxyfile` for my source code project that works. It outputs warnings since some of the comments are not maintained very well.

I would like to integrate doxygen as some kind of prebuild step, so that warnings are appear in the IDE (visual Studio 2010 and 2015).

But this should work on a per-file-base.

Is there some possibility or alternative to use doxygen parser just to check the consistency of the comments for only a single file (and without generating any other output).

Comment: You probably would need to generate the Doxyfile based on the file you want to check inside Visual Studio (also look at the \INCLUDE in the Configuration section of the manual to have the other parameters in the configuration fixed). I think this is more a Visual Studio problem then a doxygen problem

Comment: @albert then please mentally replace visual studio with eclipse. still its not possible to parse just a single file. Doxygenning the whole project tooks 10minutes or so. and generating a single Doxyfile for each file seems not that comfortable

Comment: I don't think it is a difference whether it is Visual Studio or Eclipse. I thought you just wanted it to be when rebuilding a single file. Maybe you can get from the underlying make process a list of all files that have been changed and do here the "single file" version. I was thinking about  to adjust your compilation command in such a way that it runs doxygen before compiling a file but this might be problematic due to dependencies (resulting in non changed files to be recompiled due to the fact that e.g. an include file changed).